# How to listen click event and when clicked find parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have html like this

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <div class="abc">
        <div class="def"><a class="btn"></a></div>
        <h3>B</h3>
        <p><a class="btn">C</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I listen click event on `<a class="btn">C</a>` and than find value of `<h2>A</h2>` (A)?

Here is my try

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function (event) {
    var btn = event.target, container;
    container = $(btn).closest('h2');
    window.console.log(container);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Consider giving the [documentation for `.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com) a good read.

Comment: ...also consider browsing the [documentation for traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). That should give you all the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  alert( $(this).closest('.abc').prev().text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <div class="abc">
        <div class="close"><a class="btn"></a></div>
        <h3>B</h3>
        <p><a class="btn">C</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```